# Some styles are not working?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using following content slider [slider](http://bxslider.com/). For its forward and back button i am applying styles for eg `text-indent` and `width,height` but its not working. Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/3WtJ8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-indent`, `width` and `height` can only be applied to block-level elements. By default an `a` element is inline.

If you add the style: `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to your `.bx-prev` style it should work, however inline-block may not be recognised by IE7 or lower without using something like [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3WtJ8/2/)

Comment: depending on the css-rules applied (absolute positioning), you could use display:block; to prevent issues in lower IEs. In IE7 you can set the rules: `display:inline-block` **and** `display:inline` to make IE/ treat the element like inline-block. thanks to hasLayout

Comment: @Christoph True. You could also float the block element too.